# orientdb - Merge the edge, add the number of edges and details as Attrubute

Tags: merge, graph-theory, orientdb

I am studying the analysis method using **orientdb** related to traveler analysis.

Not enough, but a lot of help.

I want to visualize `traveler X aircraft X traveler` through `orientdb`

I would like to change the query results in orientdb more clearly.

In Korea, there are not many projects and materials through orientdb.

I've done a lot of searches through Google, but have not been able to find the same one, so I'm posting this in person.

I used ETL to load the CSV's data and visualize it on the graph.

Of course, the displayed graph shows exactly the data you want.

However, I like the attached Edge image.

I would like to merge the Edge and show the number of it and the information of the merged Edge.

I have tried many times using ETL Config.

It doesn't work ....

I would like to ask for advice on both **SQL and ETL**.

[image]